# How do a call a method from the ApplicationController before every method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do this `update_activity_time` everytime a user does something in the app.

Ive done this http://blog.tmisoft.com/2009/09/restful-authentication-session-timeout.html

the error I get is undefined local variable or method when I did

before_filter update_activity_time at the top of my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `before_filter :update_activity_time`